# R's XML example not working - xmlToDataFrame

Tags: xml, r

With the next code:

---

```
library(XML)

f = system.file("exampleData", "size.xml", package = "XML")
doc = xmlParse(f)
z = xmlToDataFrame(f, colClasses = list("integer", "integer", "numeric"))
y = xmlToDataFrame(nodes = xmlChildren(xmlRoot(doc)[["size"]]))

browser()
```

---

I get these results :

```
Browse[1]> z
  age sex number
1   0   0    500
2   0   1    300
3   1   0    200
4   1   1    400
5  10   0     NA
Browse[1]> y
  text
1    0
2    0
3  500
```

This is from package help and following the manual, what can be wrong? The results for y are not the same for z, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't copy the entire example. I get the same error when I just copy those two lines from the example, but no error when I copy the entire example from ?xmlToDataFrame .

(I have done this twice and I have not figured out which of the arguments is not being passed properly, and so my working hypothesis is that some connections is not established properly.)

EDIT; (now an entirely different question)
Because the root is different than the whole file:

```
> xmlRoot(doc)[["size"]]
<size>
  <age>0</age>
  <sex>0</sex>
  <number>500</number>
</size>
```

EDIT2: You do not need to specify the colClasses:

```
>  xmlToDataFrame(f)
  age sex number
1   0   0    500
2   0   1    300
3   1   0    200
4   1   1    400
5  10   0   <NA>
```

And if you want the read.table behavior of guessing at the class from the first five lines of data then you can do a write/read.table operation:

```
> write.table(xmlToDataFrame(f), file="test.txt", quote=FALSE)
> read.table(file="test.txt")
> str(read.table(file="test.txt"))
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ age   : int  0 0 1 1 10
 $ sex   : int  0 1 0 1 0
 $ number: int  500 300 200 400 NA
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I just edited the question to another issue. Can you help? Thank you very much.

Comment: so how can I get the complete data frame with all the size fields with this kind of approach described of the manual?

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking this question ... which is again different that either of the two prior questions. The 'z' object would appear to contain all of the information in the 'size' file and it is in the form of a data.frame.

Comment: The thing is with z = xmlToDataFrame(f, colClasses = list("integer", "integer", "numeric")) I have to input the colClasses for all the 3 results (age, sex and number). With y = xmlToDataFrame(nodes = xmlChildren(xmlRoot(doc)[["size"]])) it seems I don't need to do that. Now imagine I wan´t to use one of these methods to get a dataframe with a different file with 30 or more results inside size, that would be painful ;-).We have a way of doing something like y = xmlToDataFrame(nodes = "size") to have what I want i.e. a  similar result to z dataframe?Sorry for my English, thanks for your patience

Comment: Thanks, I think this particular question is answered

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice but I'm getting problems trying xmlToDataFrame to work with some XML(How can I upload the file I'm using so you can check it?)

Comment: I think this would be a separate question if the interchange is to be through SO. Looking at other questions that have been posed, it appears that people have simply been posting the XML text in the body of the question.

Comment: Something like z = xmlToDataFrame(f, colClasses = colClasses("3c30i")) might help for a different file with many children inside size.